# How to get around duplicate code Mongo/Core API

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have two entities:

```
public class EndUser
{
    public const string CollectionName = "Clients";

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class AppDeveloper : EndUser
{
    [BsonElement("CompanyName")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("CompanyAdress")]
    public string CompanyAdress { get; set; }
}
```

and create a context for Mongo DB

```
public class MongoContext
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database = null;

    public MongoContext(IOptions<MongoSettings> _settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(_settings.Value.ConnectionString);
        if (client != null)
            _database = client.GetDatabase(_settings.Value.Database);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<EndUser> Users
    {
        get
        {
            IMongoCollection<EndUser> dbConnection = _database.GetCollection<EndUser>(EndUser.CollectionName);
            return dbConnection;
        }
    }

    public IMongoCollection<AppDeveloper> Developers
    {
        get
        {
            IMongoCollection<AppDeveloper> dbConnection = _database.GetCollection<AppDeveloper>(AppDeveloper.CollectionName);
            return dbConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

and now I have the problem with duplicate code, for example:

user implementation

```
public class UserRepository : IMainMongoRepository<EndUser>, IClientSearching<EndUser>
{
    private readonly MongoContext mongoContext = null;

    public UserRepository(MongoContext mongoContext)
    {
        this.mongoContext = mongoContext;
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(EndUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            await mongoContext.Users.InsertOneAsync(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public async Task<EndUser> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            FilterDefinition<EndUser> filter = Builders<EndUser>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);
            EndUser user = await mongoContext.Users.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return user;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and developer implementation

```
 public class DeveloperRepository : IMainMongoRepository<AppDeveloper>, IClientSearching<AppDeveloper>
{
    private readonly MongoContext mongoContext = null;

    public DeveloperRepository(MongoContext mongoContext)
    {
        this.mongoContext = mongoContext;
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(AppDeveloper developer)
    {
        try
        {
            await mongoContext.Developers.InsertOneAsync(developer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public async Task<AppDeveloper> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            FilterDefinition<AppDeveloper> filter = Builders<AppDeveloper>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);
            AppDeveloper developer = await mongoContext.Developers.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return developer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

In this example I have the same realization for different models. It's bad to have the same code (now I have just two models, but if I take 10), which I don't know how to fix. How can I create right code without duplicating code? (models should save in one collection)

I have CRUD for this models and most part of implementation have the same problem.

Comment: If the only difference is the Types handled, you could go for [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: If you see more attentively, you notice the problem besides type (`mongoContext.Developers.` and `mongoContext.Users`), I don't know how fix this two for 1!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
public class MongoContext<T>
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database = null;
    private readonly string _collection = null;

    public MongoContext(IOptions<MongoSettings> _settings, string collection)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(_settings.Value.ConnectionString);
        if (client != null)
            _database = client.GetDatabase(_settings.Value.Database);
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public IMongoCollection<T> Objects
    {
        get
        {
            IMongoCollection<T> dbConnection = _database.GetCollection<T>(_collection);
            return dbConnection;
        }
    }
}

public class Repository<T> : IMainMongoRepository<T>, IClientSearching<T>
{
    private readonly MongoContext<T> mongoContext = null;

    public Repository(MongoContext<T> mongoContext)
    {
        this.mongoContext = mongoContext;
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            await mongoContext.Objects.InsertOneAsync(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            FilterDefinition<T> filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);
            T obj = await mongoContext.Objects.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you write `private readonly string _collection = null;`  to send the name of collection, how write if I create different collection

Comment: In this code the collection can be setted on MongoContext creation (see 'string collection' in constructor)